# Center Image from assets folder in a Webview

Tags: android, html, webview, center

I am displaying images from the assets folder in a WebView, which is also zoomed out all the way to see the whole content. Is there a way to center the image in the Webview instead of the default top left corner?

Answer (score 0):

You should load your images in a www recognizable file , i think best is .html
 for example:

```
<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>
```

either hard coded style inside the img TAG is required or use an external stylesheet, what should be inside your assets folder aswell.

To give you an idea:

http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol7/html_no10.htm

Comment: Thank you for your post. I was informed that I forgot to mark that it was android so this didn't quite work for what I needed. The following code is what I was able to use to get it to work, sort-of.
viewPictures.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/","<html><center><img src=\"" + imageName + "\"></html>","text/html","utf-8","");

Comment: i understood it was for android.That doesn't make html any different.
Glad you got it worked out. ;)